# New version ADB doesn't recognize iBall Slide 6309i(Android 4.1.1)

Tags: android, adb

**Device:** iBall Slide 6309i

**Platform:** Android 4.1.1

**Tested with OS (on PC):** Win XP, Win 7 x64, Win 8 x64, Ubuntu 13.04

**ADB drivers are installed and working.**
*USB debugging enabled.***

**Problem:** My device is being detected with ADB v1.0.26. But when i try with any of the later versions like 1.0.29, 1.0.31, the device is not detected. Its the same in all the OSes i've tested. The older version of ADB don't have some key functions like backup, restore. So I'm compelled to use newer version with no joy. I'm unable to find a way to trick the newer version ADB to detect my device. Kindly suggest a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

`adb` has a hard-coded "whitelist" of USB Vendor IDs. If your device's manufacturer is not on that list - you need to add the device's Vendor ID in `0xffff` format to `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` (or `%USERPROFILE%\.android\adb_usb.ini` in Windows). For more details check this [adb device detection](http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html) 
page.